# Suppose $n=917,4X8,835$ where $X$ is the missing digit. Find possible values of $X$ so that $n$ is divisible by $\{2,3,9,25\}$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Suppose $n=917,4X8,835$ where X is the missing digit. Find possible
>   values of $X$ so that $n$ is divisible by each of the integers:
>   $${2,3,9,25}.$$

I'm a bit confused by the inconsistency by validating if it's possible with the integers.

For example, when checking if it's divisible by $2$ then it just states "$2$ cannot divide $n$, because $2 \nmid 5$ so therefore $2 \nmid n$ for any $X$." Fair enough makes sense.

But then for finding an $X$ that divides $n$ by $3$, then it states "If the sum of all the digits in $n$ is divisible by $3$ then it is divisible by $3$." Which also makes sense, but how come we couldn't do that for $2$ as well? $3 \nmid 5$ as well so if I apply the same logic from $2$ then then there  can't be an $X$ right? I don't really understand what's going on. Same with when finding an $X$ that divides it by $9$, shouldn't the last digit need to be dividable by $9$? Then for checking for divisibility by $25$ it just checks the last $2$ digits($35$) is divisible by $25$. Can anyone explain why this is?

In what cases do you check if the "last k digits" are divisible by an integer that is k digits long? What cases do you sum up digits of $n$ and find the $X\in[0,9]$ that makes the sum divisible by the integer?

Comment: You should check divisibility rules. They are not the same for every divisor. What's being referenced here is that a number is divisible by $2$ if and only if its last digit is divisible by $2$, and also that a number is divisible by $3$ if and only the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$. These rules are not interchangeable. $12$ is divisible by $2$ even though $1+2 = 3$ is not, and $27$ is divisible by $3$ even though its last digit $7$ is not. There are other rules for other  numbers, and these rules can generally be derived through prime decomposition or modular arithmetic.

Comment: awesome thanks!

Comment: How come for 3 it requires a sum of the digits? What's special about 3?

Comment: How come for 7 it's double the last digit and minus it from the others? Then if that's divisible by 7 it's divisible?

Comment: @user8714896 In theory, what you do when you perform that test is subtracting 21 until the last digit is $0$, then divide by 10. Neither of those things change whether the number is divisible by 7. You can also take the last three digits and subtract it from the others. As 1001 is divisible by 7,11 and 13, this test works for those three integers.

Comment: And what makes 3 special? It's a divisor of 9, and 9 is 10-1, and 10 is the base of our number system.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the number
$$n:=917\,4X8\,835=X\cdot10^4+917\,408\,835$$
cannot be divisible by $2$ or $25$, whatever $X\in[0\,..\,9]$. Therefore there can be no $X$ making $n$ divisible by "each" number in the list $\{2,3,9,25\}$.

If you think about divisibility by individual numbers in this list the cases $3$ and $9$ remain. Since $10^k=1$ mod $3$ and mod $9$, whatever $k\geq0$, we have to sum the digits of $n':=917\,408\,835$ in order to find the remainders of $n'$ mod $3$ and mod $9$. We find $$917\,408\,835=9+1+7+4+8+8+3+5=45=0\qquad({\rm mod}\ 3, \ {\rm mod}\ 9)\ .$$

In order to make $n$ divisible by $3$ we therefore have to choose $X=0$ mod $3$, hence $X\in\{0,3,6,9\}$.

In order to make $n$ divisible by $9$ we  have to choose $X=0$ mod $9$, hence $X\in\{0,9\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints on divisibility rules

---

You may need some knowledge in modular arithmetic.

Let $x\in\mathbb{N}$ then we can express $x$ as
$$
x=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\cdot 10^i, \quad \text{where}\quad a_i\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}.
$$

So

$$
x=a_0\cdot10^0+a_1\cdot 10^1+\ldots +a_n\cdot 10^n
$$

and for divisbility by $3$ let us reduce $x$ modulo $3$, which means we substitute for each number with the rest after we divided said number by $3$.

$$
10=3\cdot 3+1
$$

that is the rest is $1$, so $10\equiv 1\ \bmod 3$ which means.

$$
x=a_0\cdot10^0+a_1\cdot 10^1+\ldots +a_n\cdot 10^n\to x=a_0\cdot1^0+a_1\cdot 1^1+\ldots +a_n\cdot 1^n=
$$
$$
=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n
$$

which means that $x$ and the same rest when divided by $3$ as the sum of its digits which in turn means that if the digitsum is divisible then the number is also.

The exact same argument works for divisibility by $9$.

Divisibility by $11$ is also a fun one, I challenge you to try out yourself (HINT: $11\equiv -1\ \bmod 10$)